# Microsoft Edge WebGL lose context

Tags: three.js, webgl, microsoft-edge

I m creating a THREE.js (latest version, r71) app, and sometimes I need to manually delete the 3D scene to display classic 2D content. So, what I do is clearing all variables like scene or renderer, and killing the WebGL context using `renderer.forceContextLoss()`

This method works fine on Firefox or Chrome, but it is not supported on Interner Explorer or Microsoft Edge, which cause multiple lags on my web page. I can't find a workaround to do this properly as I do in Firefox or Chrome.

If someone has a tip, feel free to tell me :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try using two canvas tags and put one over the other as suggested [here](http://html5.litten.com/using-multiple-html5-canvases-as-layers/),
put them in a parent div tag then use the following css.

```
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
```

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment, allow me to clarify my understanding.

- You want to draw 2d and 3d.
- You are resetting the webGL context.

You can't have 2 contexts to the same canvas simultaneously and **I assume** you want to use a a different context for your 2d content.

**If this assumption is correct:**
I am suggesting that you have 2 canvases and contexts simultaneously, one with your webGL context and 3d content, and another with the context you want to use for 2d content. Then you overlay these canvases by using absolute position, such that it looks like there is one canvas.
This means you never have to reload assets to switch contexts, just make sure you so the above canvas is transparent.

Also if you wrap the canvas in a div tag, it will not be at the top left of the page.

**But If my assumption is wrong:**
perhaps you don't want to use another context and just wish to clear the screen, in which case you should not call `forceContextLoss()`

If you wish to continue to use the webGL context, but clear the screen you should use [`clear()`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer.clear)

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this. Why using two canvas at top left of the page ? I need to clear my WebGL canvas properly, I can't understand why creating 2 canvas could help me. Plus, my canvas is WebGL, not 2D.

Comment: Thanks for this edit. Your assumption is correct. But what I don't like with this approach is loading both canvases (2D and 3D). Imagine an user with a low-hardware device, if it can't support WebGL, the 2D canvas will be shown, but the 3D canvas will still be active in the background (which leads to performance loss)

Comment: If webGL isn't supported then the 3D canvas won't be active...

Also when you force context loss, you are forced to send all assets to the GPU again. This is probably the biggest bottleneck in 3d rendering today, the sharing of content such as sharers and between the GPU and CPU.

But rather than speculate, profile it and see. You can't optimize by speculation.